# confirm quit when user presses X button

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

i'd like to ask the user "Are you sure that you want to quit the application?" question. If the user presses Yes, the application will terminate. If the user the presses No, the application will continue running. How do i do that?

I use visual c++ 2008 and mfc.

Comment: This kind of UI is just awful, most users will look for the uninstaller next.  The more typically appropriate message is "You'll lose ten minutes of your life when you click Yes and meant No".  Write better code, make sure the user is up and running again with no loss of data in less than 10 seconds.

Answer (score 2):

You need to handle the `WM_CLOSE` message, which can do in MFC by [adding `ON_WM_CLOSE` to your `CMainFrame` class's message map](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16694848/366904), and providing an implementation of the `OnClose` function.

(The Class Wizard can do this for you.)

```
void CMainFrame::OnClose()
{
    if (AfxMessageBox("Exit application?", MB_YESNO) == IDYES)
        __super::OnClose();
}
```

[`__super`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/94dw1w7x.aspx) is an MSVC extension that allows you to refer to the most immediate base class. If you are compiling in another compiler (unlikely for an MFC app), or using non-standard extensions makes you uncomfortable, you can substitute the actual name of the base class.

Comment: error C2248: 'CFrameWnd::OnClose' : cannot access protected member declared in class 'CFrameWnd'

Comment: error C2352: 'CFrameWnd::OnClose' : illegal call of non-static member function

Comment: Don't call it  within the Main class structure. and try to change void CMainFrame into static void CMainFrame.

Comment: Oh and don't bother using Google. :)

Answer (score 0):

The approach suggested by Marijke is correct. But for it to compile you must add ON_WM_CLOSE in the CMainFrame message map, and you must use the actual base class where Marijke used CFrameWnd. (There are several possible base classes.) For example, the message map could look like this if the base class is CMDIFrameWndEx:

```
BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CMainFrame, CMDIFrameWndEx)
ON_WM_CREATE()
ON_WM_CLOSE()
....
```